# ML Crossentropy Bug

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
ERROR:
Node: 'binary_crossentropy/Cast'
Cast string to float is not supported
\[\[{{node binary_crossentropy/Cast}}\]\] \[Op:\__inference_train_function_146981\]
```

Working on a problem to input "title", "text" of a dataframe and output 0 or 1, "fake" or "real" news. Here would be the relevant code.

Dataframe columns

```py
Unnamed: 0     int64
title         object
text          object
fake           int64
dtype: object
```

```py
def remove_stopwords(text):
    words = text.split()
    filtered_words = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in stop]
    filtered_text = ' '.join(filtered_words)
    return filtered_text

def make_dataset(df):
    df['title'] = df['title'].apply(remove_stopwords)
    df['text'] = df['text'].apply(remove_stopwords)
    X_title = df['title'].values
    X_text = df['text'].values
    y = df['fake'].values.astype(mp.float32)  # Convert target variable to float
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_title, X_text, y))

dataset = make_dataset(train_url)

train_size = 0.8
validation_size = 0.2

# Calculate the number of examples for each split
num_examples = len(dataset)
num_train_examples = int(train_size * num_examples)
num_val_examples = int(validation_size * num_examples)

# Split the dataset
train_dataset = dataset.take(num_train_examples)
val_dataset = dataset.skip(num_train_examples).take(num_val_examples)
# Convert string labels to float
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x_title, x_text, y: (x_title, x_text, tf.cast(y, tf.float32)))
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(lambda x_title, x_text, y: (x_title, x_text, tf.cast(y, tf.float32)))
```

```py
#preparing a text vectorization layer for tf model
size_vocabulary = 2000

def standardization(input_data):
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
    no_punctuation = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase,
                                  '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation),'')
    return no_punctuation 

title_vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize=standardization,
    max_tokens=size_vocabulary, # only consider this many words
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=500) 

title_vectorize_layer.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda x_title, x_text, y: x_title))

text_vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize=standardization,
    max_tokens=size_vocabulary,  # only consider this many words
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=500)

text_vectorize_layer.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda x_title, x_text, y: x_text))
```

```py
# Model 1
title_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
title_vectorized = title_vectorize_layer(title_input)
title_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(size_vocabulary, 32, input_length=500)(title_vectorized)
title_flattened = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(title_embedding)
output_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(title_flattened)
model_1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=title_input, outputs=output_1)
```

I've tried playing wiht the types of data is output in the preprocessing and asking GPT, but seems like nothing has worked so far

Comment: This sounds like your labels are strings instead of 0/1, which will never work, they need to be binary values.